# Text is not changed with OnClientClick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new to Javascript. I wrote a code, but it does not work as I wish. This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript';
    }
</script>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="HelloJavaScript" style="height: 157px">

    <p id="demo">JavaScript can change the HTML content</p>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="changeText()"/>

</div>
</form>
```

The text is not changed once I click the button. What's wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add one more `Property` in your button tag `UseSubmitBehavior = false` to avoid submitting form and do a postback.

Answer (score 2):

It'll create postback

try like this

```
OnClientClick="changeText();return false;"
```

OR like this

JS

```
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript';
    return false;
}
```

Html

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="return changeText();" />
```

**N:B:**

Using `return` in `OnClientClick` will prevent form going to server.

You have to handle `return` logically according to your business

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" onclick="changeText()"/>
```

Use onclick instead of OnClientClick

Answer (score 0):

```
        <p id="demo">JavaScript can change the HTML content</p>

        <button type="button" onClick="changeText()">Click Me!</button>

<script>
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript';}
</script>
```